# angular slow select input

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

in my controller, is set the two scope variables "otherscope" and "options".

```
otherscope: {"ID":"1", "VAL1":"X", "VAL2":"Y", ...}
```

othersope.ID is the value, which should be the selected one. it contains 1 object

```
options: [{"ID":"1", "TEXT":"Sometext"}, {"ID":"2":"Sometext2"}, ...]
```

options.ID are the available options to compare with otherscope.ID. it contains about 50 objects.

it works, but it take about 10 seconds to render. is this the correct way to set the selected value?

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
              Options
            </div>
            <select ng-model="otherscope.ID">
              <option ng-repeat="option in options track by option.ID" value="{{option.ID}}">{{option.TEXT}}</option>
            </select>
          </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

change options to option in ng-repeat

```
<option ng-repeat="options in options track by option.ID" value="{{option.ID}}">{{option.TEXT}}</option>
```

should be:

```
<option ng-repeat="option in options track by option.ID" value="{{option.ID}}">{{option.TEXT}}</option>
```

Comment: very strange plnkr can help.
try : <select  ng-options="option.TEXT for option in options track by option.ID"
      ng-model="otherscope.ID"></select>

Comment: this renders fast, but appends an option at the end with an undefined value which is selected.

Comment: your otherscope object should be the same as one of your objects in the options.
e.g: otherscope = {"ID":"1", "TEXT":"Sometext"};